# Importing an MS Excel spreadsheet without header into an existing MS Access Table

Tags: excel, ms-access-2013

I have a process where I import a text file into an exist Access Table (columns/fields named). The text file does not have column headers. The users want the option of being able to import that same file after it has been converted and MS Excel Spreadsheet to the same Access table. When I use the Docmd.TransferSpreadsheet function I get an error message

> Field 'F1' doesn't exist in destination table.

Is there a way to import the Excel file so that it doesn't try to match up headers between the two applications?

TIA
David Fournier

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem recently. I couldn't find any solution from Access. So I just use VBA to open the file in Excel and add the header row.

Below is my code for reference.

```
Dim XL As Object

Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With XL
    .Visible = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Workbooks.open sFile 'sFile is your excel spreadsheet full file path 
    Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A1") = "xxxxx" 'ColumnA header
    Range("B1") = "xxxxx" 'ColumnB header
    Range("C1") = "xxxxx" 'ColumnC header
    ''
    ''
    'you can add as many column header you want

    .ActiveWorkbook.Save True
    .Quit
End With
Set XL = Nothing

'Now you can use docmd.transferspreadsheet

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "tblName", sFile, True
```

Good luck. Please let me know if you have better way to do this.

Cheers